# VBA how to loop text every 50 rows

Tags: vba, excel

How can I insert a specific text every 4 rows for 3 rows until the last row of my worksheet?

```
1
2
3
4
5 Hello
6 Hello
7 Hello
8
9
10
11
12 Hello
13 Hello
14 Hello
15
16
17 
18
19 Hello
.
.
500 Hello
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Dim i As Long
For i = 57 To Rows.Count Step 55
    Cells(i, 1) = "Hello"
Next i
which gives me sort of what i want. but i need to be able to say hello for the next ten row. so it needs to be row 57-67 "hello" next 55 rows blanks then row 122-132 " hello next 55 rows blanks until the end of worksheet

Comment: Please try to avoid changing your question after you've asked it. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are not well liked here. It's usually a good idea to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve in your question, so that people won't needlessly give you answers that only solve the problem you've described, not the problem you really have.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `Step` function

If you just want the `Text` every 5 rows use:

```
For i = 1 To 500 Step 5
    Cells(i, 1) = "Hello"
Next i
```

If you want a value and then `Text` every 5 rows use:

```
For i = 1 To 500 Step 5
    If rowCount = 5 Then
        Cells(i, 1) = "Hello"
        rowCount = 0
    Else
        Cells(i, 1) = i
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    End If
Next i
```

If you want to consider a variable row range then use the following in place of 500:

```
Cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).row
```

***Update for after question was edited***
This will do what your new question is asking for

```
Dim i As Long

' Change this to your actual sheet
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 7 Step 7
        With .Cells(i, "A")
            Range(.Offset(4, 0), .Offset(6, 0)).Value2 = "Hello"
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: thank you, what if the lenght of my report is variable. so everytime i run my report the lenght its different, sometimes its 500 rows and sometimes its 1000 rows. how can i loop this so that the lenght of the report is variable?

Comment: I've added how to get the last row in my answer. [Have a look at this for more information](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for the heads up - have updated